# Gradle transitive dependency doesn't respect version

Tags: gradle, dependencies, dependency-resolution

I have a Gradle 3.5 project, and in that project I depend on an artifact:

```
compile "a.b.c:depProject:1.1.0"
```

"depProject" is a Maven project, where in that project's pom file, it depends on another artifact:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
   </dependency>
```

Now, when I perform "gradle dependencies" on my project, it correctly shows that I should get the solrj dependency via transitive dependency resolution, but it doesn't respect the 4.4.0 version declaration, instead my project gains a dependency on version 5.5.4.

```
+--- a.b.c:depProject:1.1.0
|    \--- org.apache.solr:solr-solrj:4.4.0 -> 5.5.4
```

These lines appear several times in the dependency report, always the same.

Why is Gradle "upgrading" my dependency automatically?  Is there a way to get this to stop, other than to directly depend on the transitive dependency, specifying the version I want?

Note, if I exclude the solrj dependency in my project via:

```
compile ("a.b.c:depProject:1.1.0") {
    exclude group:"org.apache.solr" module:"solr-solrj"
}
```

Then there is NO solrj dependency in the resulting "gradle dependencies" call, so there is no other place that solrj is being depended on at that higher version.

I can't post the entire build.gradle, but I can show what plugins are applied:

```
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"com.moowork.node"
apply plugin:"org.grails.plugins.views-json"
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-gsp"
apply plugin: "maven"
apply plugin: "codenarc"
apply plugin: "jacoco"
apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"
apply plugin: "asset-pipeline"
```

Comment: Did you use some plugin to bump the version, it is weird that even the `5.5.4` is not the latest either. It would be nice to paste the full `build.gradle`.

Comment: @chenrui I did add the plugins applied in the build.gradle.

Comment: If you can also paste the `buildSrc` part, it would be great for me to debug thru.

Comment: There is no buildSrc section in the file.

Comment: But your contention is that this *shouldn't* be happening, and the fact that it is points to one of the plugins performing an upgrade to the version?   You should note that if I add a direct dependency to the solrj library v4.4.0, it does correct the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I thought some plugin may do the version bump, as when you exclude the solr dependency, there is no solr dependency in the project, right?

Comment: Right, the only artifact in the build dependency list that depends on solrj is the one in question, as excluding it from that dependency removes solrj altogether from the project.

Answer (score 1):

Gradle only picks a newer version of a dependency if there is a conflict between two transitive dependencies. So either you found a bug in gradle, or something else in your project depends on

```
org.apache.solr:solr-solrj:5.5.4
```

Just run

```
gradle dependencies | grep -B5 solrj:5
```

And see if there really is no dependency to that version.

You can also force a certain resolution, searching for `gradle force version` will give you answers quickly, but since this would downgrade solrj, you should first find out what's wrong before deciding.